# Scrollable Tabs with adjustable height of the Tabs in android

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, android-scrollable-tabs

I am trying to implement scrollable tabs with custom height of the tabs. 
I have searched a lot and found that even though ActionBar is the latest thing, it somehow doesn't support changing the height of the tab navigation bar.

I know this has probably been asked before but could someone help with me with a work around for adjusting the height of the tabs via ActionBar.

minSDKVersion = 14
targetSDKVersion = 18

Thanks.
Sunny

UPDATE: veiwpager used in the xml Layout

```
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
```

Comment: Are you using viewpager?

Comment: yes, i am for the swiping of the fragments. is that creating an issue? Changing height of the tabs is the major thing. I can live with just scrolling tabs and no scrolling for the fragments

Comment: Can you post your layout where you are using viewpager?

Comment: @keshav ..i have posted the view pager that i used. please let me know if any other info is required

Comment: you have posted only viewpager ,I have asked for layout(whole) containing viewpager.

Comment: ok so this is how i went about it. I just had the veiw pager in the main xml. Then in the activity I added the action bar and added the tabs to the action bar and set navigation mode and set the listners. I had a veiwpage adaptor where I added the fragments based on the tab clicked